# JSSOR Slider - frame overlay for images

Tags: slider, frame, jssor

I have a slider with fixed image sizes (all pictures are the same size), and need to know please if it is possible to **overlay** the slider container with a frame that has a transparent middle to let the slides **underneath** show through. Adding the frame to each individual slide image doesn't look good, because the frame is then "ripped apart" by the image transitions. I need a frame "overlay" that stays in place and intact **above** the individual slides.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add anything in a slider container. And you can add static content in slides container. And you can add static content in any slide.

```
<div id="slider1_container" ...>
    <!-- custom background here
    <div ...>...</div>
    -->
    <div u="slides" ...>
        ...
        <!-- custom overlay here
        <div u="any" ...>...</div>
        -->
    </div>
    <!-- custom overlay here
    <div ...>...</div>
    -->
</div>
```